# How to combine 2 select in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have sql query which selects some stuff from first table using params from second, and then i need to get some columns from second table in addition to first
Code looks like that

```
SELECT 
  entry AS entry,
  ItemLevel AS ItemLevel,
  RequiredLevel AS RequiredLevel,
  InventoryType AS InventoryType,
  Quality AS Quality,
  class AS class,
  subclass AS subclass 
FROM item_template 
WHERE entry IN (SELECT entry FROM locales_item WHERE name_loc8 LIKE ? ) 
ORDER BY ItemLevel DESC; 

SELECT entry, name_loc8, description_loc8 FROM locales_item WHERE name_loc8 LIKE ?
```

But it's throws an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT entry, name_loc8, description_loc8 FROM locales_item WHERE name_loc8 LIKE' at line 1

How to solve this?

Comment: YOu might want to look into JOIN

Comment: You try to run 2 queries at once. How do you execute them?

Comment: @Mihai can you format it with join?

Comment: do you have a common field on the two tables? like a primary key -> foreign key relationship?

Comment: @JohnRuddell entry is a uniq key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to connect the two tables:

```
SELECT 
  item_template.entry AS entry,
  ItemLevel AS ItemLevel,
  RequiredLevel AS RequiredLevel,
  InventoryType AS InventoryType,
  Quality AS Quality,
  class AS class,
  subclass AS subclass 
FROM item_template inner join locales_item 
on item_template.entry = locales_item.entry 
 WHERE name_loc8 LIKE ?  
ORDER BY ItemLevel DESC;
```

Comment: SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?  
ORDER BY ItemLevel DESC' at line 11

Comment: I copied the `?` from your original query, you need to put there the criteria for your query

Answer (score 1):

if entry is a unique key then you can join the two tables together like so

```
SELECT it.stuff, li.stuff 
FROM item_template it 
JOIN locales_item li ON li.entry = it.entry
WHERE li.name_loc8 LIKE "some string"
ORDER BY it.ItemLevel DESC
```

this removes the need for your dependent subquery with the `IN()` since joining the table already filters like the where would

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the results of two queries you can use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), however I think what you are after here is joining the matching records in two tables into a single query which you can do with [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

With your example, I think what you're looking for is a query like this:

```
SELECT t.entry          AS entry,
       t.ItemLevel      AS ItemLevel,
       t.RequiredLevel  AS RequiredLevel,
       t.InventoryType  AS InventoryType,
       t.Quality        AS Quality,
       t.class          AS class,
       t.subclass       AS subclass,
       l.entry          AS locale_entry,
       l.name_loc8      AS name_loc8,
       l.description_loc8 AS description_loc8
FROM item_template t
INNER JOIN locales_item l ON l.entry = t.entry
WHERE l.name_loc8 LIKE ?
ORDER BY t.ItemLevel DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT 
  t1.entry AS entry,
  t2.name_loc8,
  t2.description_loc8
  t1.ItemLevel AS ItemLevel,
  t1.RequiredLevel AS RequiredLevel,
  t1.InventoryType AS InventoryType,
  t1.Quality AS Quality,
  t1.class AS class,
  subclass AS subclass 
FROM item_template t1
left join locales_item t2 on t1.entry = t2.entry 
WHERE t2.name_loc8 LIKE '%addyourtexthere%'----just change the text between the percent signs to the string your looking for  
ORDER BY ItemLevel DESC;
```

and also you don't need the "AS" after every column if you're calling it the same name.

Answer (score -1):

//use join query

SELECT a.field1,a.field2,b.field3,b.field4 FROM table1 a,table2 b WHERE
a.field1=b.field3 ORDER BY a.field4